# Configure autofac to use app.config in wcf client

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, autofac, wcf-client

Hi I'm trying to use autofac and use a wcf client.

But wondering how i can use the "client" configuration from my app.config ?
I would like to keep the settings in the config if possible?

```
public void ConfigureContainer()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder
      .Register(c => new ChannelFactory<apiSoapType>(new BasicHttpsBinding("?????")) ?????.SingleInstance();
    builder.Build();
}

//My app.config

<? xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name = "DisableServiceCertificateValidation" >
          < clientCredentials >
            < serviceCertificate >
              < authentication certificateValidationMode="None" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpsBinding>
        <binding name = "apiSoapBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth = "32" maxStringContentLength="200000000" maxArrayLength="200000000" />
          <security mode = "Transport" >
            < transport  clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint
        address = "https://somesite/api.wso"
        binding="basicHttpsBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="apiSoapBinding"
        behaviorConfiguration="DisableServiceCertificateValidation"
        contract="somename.apiSoapType"
        name="**somename.apiSoapType**"
      />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try registering the `ChannelFactory<T>` [using the `ChannelFactory<T>(string)` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms574913(v=vs.110).aspx) and passing in the endpoint name found in your config file.

```
builder
  .Register(c => new ChannelFactory<apiSoapType>("**somename.apiSoapType**"))
  .SingleInstance();
```